# Issue with android network

Tags: java, android, http, networking, charles-proxy

During the tests I see strange things.
My android app is sending some data to the server, I set connect and read timeouts(for tests I did a very short timeout like 2-3 seconds) after an timeout reached (exception thrown) I’m closing connection(connection.disconnect())
But in Charles I see strange connection data:

- sometimes connection kept alive
- Connection duration from 14 seconds up to 30+ seconds
- After I see in logs that connection timed out I still see in Charles like connection alive with icon of uploading
  There are few questions:
- It’s can be because of Charles?
- It’s can depend on servers config like client(app) closes connection and server for some reason think that connection still alive?
- if it’s an android/Java “feature” how I can to close connection immediately?

Comment: I'm answering the last one: you're simply can't. I've already tried.

Comment: Can you include the code you are using to disconnect? Also, when you say that a connection is still alive, do you mean that Android is keep a connection up or some other framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tests and investigation into the issue, I've found that Charles keeps alive the connection. Tested on local simple server which logs connection and as a result I saw that while there is no Charles connection has been closed after java's disconnect() and with Charles connection still alive until some timeout(think defined in Charles)